# How to find the gradient of norm square

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to find the gradient of the function $f(x) = ||g(x)||^2$

where $x \in \Bbb R^d$ and $g: \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: did you try to write explicitly the function $f$?

Comment: Is your question correct? Since the range of g is R, the norm is pointless, f(x) is simply g(x)^2, so gradient is simply 2g(x)dg/dx

Answer (score 9):

I will assume $g:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^n$.

It's nice to avoid using components.  Notice that
\begin{equation}
f(x) = h(g(x))
\end{equation}
where $h(x) = \|x\|^2$.
The chain rule tells us that
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= h'(g(x)) g'(x) \\
&= 2 \underbrace{g(x)^T}_{1 \times n} \underbrace{g'(x)}_{n \times d}.
\end{align}

If we use the convention that $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector, rather than a row vector, then
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x) = f'(x)^T = 2 g'(x)^T g(x).
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you explain why $h'(x)=2x^T$, not $h'(x)=2x$?

Comment: @Gobi Late reply here, but if $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $x$, then $F'(x)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.  So, because $h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, it must be that $h'(x)$ is a $1 \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @Gobi One of the main uses of $h'(x)$ is to perform a linear approximation: $h(x + \delta x) \approx h(x) + h'(x) \cdot \delta x$. Vectors are "by default convention" column vectors. If $x$ and $\delta x$ are taken to be column vectors, then by choosing $h'(x)$ to be a row vector, you can make sense of $h'(x) \cdot \delta x$ (

Comment: @littleO I'm self studying and badly looking for books to self learn these topics. While I prefer  'Calculus volume 2, Tom Apostol ' over 'Calculus of several variables, serge lang', Apostol's book seems too much abstract.  Would you pls suggest some more books that can help me understand the topics, books that have some simpler exercise/solution and practical examples. It would be a great help for me. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2):

The $k$-th component of the gradient is
$$
\partial_k f
= \partial_k g^2
= 2 g \partial_k g
$$
So we get
$$
\mbox{grad } f = 2 g \, \mbox{grad } g
$$

If $g$ is more-dimensional, we have:
$$
\partial_k f
= \partial_k \sum_i g_i^2
= \sum_i 2 g_i \partial_k g_i
$$
So we get
$$
\mbox{grad } f = 2 J_g^T g
$$
with $(J_g)_{ij} = \partial g_i / \partial x_j$.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we know $x = (x_1,...,x_d) $, hence,

$$ ||x||^2 = x_1^2 + ... + x_d^2 $$

Now,

$$ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_1 } = 2x_1$$

$$ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_2 } = 2x_2 $$

....

$$ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_k } = 2x_k $$

Hence,

$$ grad(f) = (2x_1,....,2x_d) = 2 x $$

Comment: Um, OP doesn't seem to be asking about $\nabla f(x)$ where $f(x)=\|x\|^2$, but rather of the composition of this function with another function. So this seems to be an answer to another question…